# Trying to change how images are requested from Cloudinary via Nginx

Tags: nginx, cloudinary, laravel-forge

We have a lot of images on Cloudinary that we are requesting using original URLs with the `<img>` tag, and we are trying to find a way to request these images with paramters, without changing any information in the database. For example, we have an image like this:

`<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/nameofmyimage.jpg">`

and when we request the image from Cloudinary, we would like it to request an image like:

`<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/w_1920,c_limit/q_auto/nameofmyimage.jpg">`

We could do global search and replaces, but the people actually working on the site wouldn't know to put these parameters in the URL in the future; they just copy and paste the image URL from Cloudinary. Is there a way to use Nginx to rewrite or proxy these URLs to include parameters? I've tried three different ways below but non work.

#1

```
location = https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/(.*)/(.*)$ {
    return 301 https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/w_1920,c_limit/q_auto/$1/$2;
}
```

#3

```
rewrite https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/(.*)/(.*)$ http://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/w_1920,c_limit/q_auto/$1/$2 last;
```

#2

```
rewrite ^/image/upload/(.*)/(.*)$ https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/w_1920,c_limit/q_auto/$1/$2 last;
```

Comment: Your NGINX has nothing to do with it. You are proxying requests through an image optimizer CDN. The only way to do what you want is by "global search and replaces".

Comment: If that's the case then I may have to modify the code itself to filter the URLs when requesting the data. I thought something globally on the server could be done.

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate the `img` tag?

If you use one of Cloudinary's SDKs for that then you can set the URL transformation upon the tag creation. You can check some Node examples [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#quick_example_transformations).

Comment: The ``img`` tag is added via TinyMCE

Answer (score 0):

add into **location / { }**

```
sub_filter_types *;
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter 'src="https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/' 'src="https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/w_1920,c_limit/q_auto/';
```

Comment: I tried this but I don't see any change. We are using Laravel Forge, and I am using the Developer Tools in Chrome to check.